# Difficulty when linking three sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am writing a paper and meeting a difficulty. I have three sentences:

1. The total drainage area is 200 square kilometers;
2. Its mainstem length is 25 km;
3. The total number of stream miles(i.e. mainstem+tributaries) contributing to this drainage is 80 km.

I need to put these 3 sentences together, and below is what I have tried:

1. The total drainage area is 200 square kilometers and its mainstem length is 25 km, with a total number of tributary as well as mainstem miles is 80 miles.

However, I think this sentence is not so fluent. Can somebody help me?

Comment: (Why do you feel you need to combine the sentences?)

Comment: Yes and why d'you think that belongs here, rather than somewhere like English Language Learners?

Comment: Well, I want to make the sentence look more "professionally"(^_^).@Drew     Thanks, Could you tell me the website of "English Language Learners"? @Robbie Goodwin

Comment: TX, you should find ELL on the top-most, right-most icon here: A list of Stack Exchange sites.

Please remember yours is a technical, not a literary paper. That means if it's possible, it will still be difficult to combine sentences like your originals  without the risk of making them less, not more clear. Just look at all those figures and units…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second sentence first: The mainstream length is 25 km and there are 80 stream miles which cause (or contribute to) a total drainage area of 200 km.